# Get Three-dimensional array differences

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am trying to write a simple method to get all the differences between comparison of two Three-dimensional arrays:

```
public static Dictionary<Int32, KeyValuePair<Int32, Double>> GetArrayDifferences3D(
        Dictionary<Int32, KeyValuePair<Int32, Double>> Array1, 
        Dictionary<Int32, KeyValuePair<Int32, Double>> Array2)
{
    Dictionary<Int32, KeyValuePair<Int32, Double>> ArrayDifferences = new Dictionary<Int32, KeyValuePair<Int32, Double>>();

    // comparison here
    return ArrayDifferences;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have the next data in Array1:

```
Int32 Int32 Double
1     2     10.50
2     2     5.00
1     1     2.00
```

And in Array2:

```
Int32 Int32 Double
5     2     1.00
3     2     0.50
1     1     5.00
```

I need to match all values ​​of type `Int32` and if they are equal then subtracted from `Double` each other and return their differences. Example:

```
Int32 Int32 Double
1     2     -10.50
2     2     -5.00
1     1      3.00 //(Match Subtract)
5     2      1.00
3     2      0.50
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? (Those also don't look like 3d arrays... more like a 2d map of doubles where only one y/value pair can be at each x.)

Comment: Hy @31eee384 please see my updated question. thanks

Comment: That are 3 arrays not 3 dimensional arrays. I also don't see win forms. And what is your problem?

Comment: Good example, that helps a lot. However you'll get better answers if you post your best attempt at the solution: "give me the code" questions are generally disliked.

Comment: You can't even have the data you say you have in `Array1` because the same key exists twice, those are not 3D arrays (`double[,,]`) but `Dictionaries`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty major speed-bump to getting a correct answer here, the data structure you propose is not capable of storing the data you propose.  A Dictionary must have a unique key but your data does not contain unique values for the first Int32.  Another problem is that you talk about *arrays*, an eminently ordered collection type, but Dictionary does not maintain order.

I'll arbitrarily fix the first problem because it has to be fixed and avoid addressing the second problem because you did not indicate an ordering requirement and to keep the code speedy.  You need a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double>` to store your data.

You are now comparing *sets*.  A simple way to generate the set of keys for the result is to use the HashSet.Union() method.  Like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double> GetSetDifference(
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double> set1,
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double> set2) 
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double>();

        var keys = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>(set1.Keys);
        keys.UnionWith(new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>(set2.Keys));

        foreach (var key in keys) {
            double value = 0;
            if (set2.ContainsKey(key)) value = set2[key];
            if (set1.ContainsKey(key)) value -= set1[key];
            result.Add(key, value);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The algorithm is O(n), can't do better than that, with O(n) storage requirements.